# RPM with HTTP/FTP URL - Storage and cleanup of package files

Tags: rpm

We are installing packages using command like below -

```
rpm -ivh https://someurl/somepackage.rpm
```

In this case, the `somepackage.rpm` would get downloaded to a local location and get installed from there. Wanted to know what that location is. More than this, the interest is to know if this temporary location is automatically cleaned up immediately or through a periodic job or if it needs to be done manually.

The official documentation or web search failed to provide a clarity on this.

Comment: Near the end of the [rpm manual page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/rpm.8.html#FILES): `Temporary /var/tmp/rpm*`. I guess this means that files are downloaded to `/var/tmp`. It is the system administrator's responsibility to occasionally remove old temporary files.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped in finding the behavior. Posted the same as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is that it is stored in `/var/tmp/` and will get cleaned up immediately after the process is complete.

This is how it was found. On one terminal instance, run the below:

```
watch -n1 du -sh /var/tmp/
```

On a different terminal, run the rpm command with a large one of around 100MB. Keep monitoring the first terminal to see the size grow until the download is in progress and post installation or failure, notice that the tmp directory is immediately cleaned and size reduces to the old value.

Thanks to @berndbausch whose comment helped in finding the answer.